# Undefined reference to `cublasCreate_v2’ in ‘/tmp/tmpxft_0000120b_0000000-10_my_program”

Tags: cuda, cublas

I have tried to compile a code using CUDA 9.0 toolkit on NVIDIA Tesla P100 graphic card (Ubuntu version 16.04) and CUBLAS library is used in the code. For compilation, I have used the following command to compile “my_program.cu”

```
nvcc -std=c++11 -L/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64 my_program.cu -o mu_program.o -lcublas
```

But, I have got the following error:

`nvlink error: Undefined reference to  'cublasCreate_v2’in '/tmp/tmpxft_0000120b_0000000-10_my_program’`

As I have already linked the library path in the compilation command, why do I still get the error. Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Usually that sort of linking error would only come up if you were trying to use the (now deprecated) CUBLAS device library. Is that the case here?

Comment: As I have used CUDA 9.0 and CUBLAS library is present in that version .How will I know that CUBLAS library is deprecated or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems fairly evident that you are trying to use the CUBLAS library **in device code**.  This is different than ordinary host usage and requires special compilation/linking steps.  You need to:

1. compile for the correct device architecture (must be cc3.5 or higher)
2. use relocatable device code linking
3. link in the cublas **device** library (in addition to the cublas host library)
4. link in the CUDA device runtime library
5. Use a CUDA toolkit prior to CUDA 10.0

The following additions to your compile command line should get you there:

```
nvcc -std=c++11 my_program.cu -o my_program.o -lcublas -arch=sm_60 -rdc=true -lcublas_device -lcudadevrt
```

The above assumes you are actually using a proper install of CUDA 9.0.  The CUBLAS device library was deprecated and is now removed from newer CUDA toolkits (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57371249/is-it-possible-to-call-cublas-or-cublaslt-functions-from-cuda-10-1-kernels/57377023#57377023)).

Deprecated and removed means that you can no longer call `cublas` functions from device code, that is any function decorated with either the `__global__` or `__device__` keyword.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. The prior issue has been solved but now  i am getting the following error:   /usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin/..//include/cuda_fp16.hpp(1487): error: more than one instance of overloaded function "isinf" matches the argument list:
            function "isinf(float)"
            function "std::isinf(float)"
            argument types are: (float)